# How to set background color for transparent pixels in MagickWand?

Tags: imagemagick, magickwand

When converting from PNG to JPG using the MagickWand API, how do I set the background to white for transparent pixels?

Answer (score 3):

```
if(current_wand && IsMagickWand(current_wand)){
    status=MagickReadImage(current_wand, "test.png");
    if (status == MagickFalse) {
        ThrowWandException(current_wand);
    }
    PixelWand *color = NewPixelWand();
    PixelSetColor(color, "white");
    MagickSetImageBackgroundColor(current_wand, color);
    MagickWand *newwand = MagickMergeImageLayers(current_wand, FlattenLayer);
    MagickWriteImage(newwand, "test.jpg");
    DestroyMagickWand(newwand);
}
```

Comment: You're probably the only person I've seen provide Objective-C source code on SO for MagickWand(). Would you mind taking a crack at my question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7480812/iphone-imagemagick-library-converting-from-batch-file-script-to-objective-c

Comment: I found that using `FlattenLayer` caused the resulting JPG to have different image dimensions (width or height) for some PNGs. Using `MergeLayer` instead fixes this for me.

Answer (score 1):

Use MagickMergeImageLayers