# iPhone ImageMagick Library - converting from batch file script to Objective-C using MagickWand API

Tags: iphone, objective-c, imagemagick, magickwand

I've decided to use the following ImageMagick library for iPhone development:

https://github.com/marforic/imagemagick_lib_iphone

It works quite well. The sample project compiles just fine, but doesn't make any sense whatsoever.

Usually, I'll use the "**convert.exe**" that comes with ImageMagick for Windows to convert images via the command line. So I'll write a little batch file like the following:

```
@echo off

set SOURCE=image_to_convert.jpg

del result.jpg
del source_copy.jpg

convert.exe %SOURCE% -fill "#fff8f2" -colorize 100%% fill.jpg

copy %SOURCE% source_copy.jpg

convert.exe %SOURCE% -modulate 100,0,100 -|^
convert.exe - source_copy.jpg -compose overlay -composite -|^
convert.exe source_copy.jpg - -compose dissolve -define compose:args=37,100 -composite -|^
convert.exe - -modulate 100,70,100 +level 3.5%%,100%% -|^
convert.exe - -channel red -level 0%%,89%% +level 9%%,100%% -|^
convert.exe - -channel green +level 3.5%%,100%% -|^
convert.exe - -channel blue -level 0%%,93%% +level 4.7%%,100%% -|^
convert.exe - -brightness-contrast -5x3 -|^
convert.exe fill.jpg - -compose multiply -gravity center -composite -|^
convert.exe - -level 3.5%%,100%%,0.91 +level 2.7%%,100%% -|^
convert.exe - -channel red +level 3.5%%,100%% -|^
convert.exe - -channel green -level 0%%,87%% +level 1%%,100%% -|^
convert.exe - -channel blue -level 0%%,100%%,0.94 +level 7%%,100%% -|^
convert.exe - -brightness-contrast -1x0 final_converted_image.jpg

del source_copy.jpg
del fill.jpg
```

The problem is converting the above batch file to be used alongside that particular library.

```
- (void)convertImage {
    MagickWandGenesis();
    magick_wand = NewMagickWand();
    //UIImageJPEGRepresentation([imageViewButton imageForState:UIControlStateNormal], 90);
    NSData * dataObject = UIImagePNGRepresentation([UIImage imageNamed:@"iphone.png"]);
    MagickBooleanType status;
    status = MagickReadImageBlob(magick_wand, [dataObject bytes], [dataObject length]);
    if (status == MagickFalse) {
        ThrowWandException(magick_wand);
    }

    // Resize image.
    ImageInfo *imageInfo = AcquireImageInfo();
    ExceptionInfo *exceptionInfo = AcquireExceptionInfo();

    // Get image from bundle.
    char *input_image = strdup([[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"iphone" ofType:@"png"] UTF8String]);
    char *output_image = strdup([[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"iphone" ofType:@"png"] UTF8String]);
    char *argv[] = { "convert", input_image, "-resize", "100x100", output_image, NULL };

    // ConvertImageCommand(ImageInfo *, int, char **, char **, MagickExceptionInfo *);
    status = ConvertImageCommand(imageInfo, 5, argv, NULL, exceptionInfo);

    free(input_image);
    free(output_image);

    if (status == MagickFalse) {
        ThrowWandException(magick_wand); // Always throws an exception here...
    }

    size_t my_size;
    unsigned char * my_image = MagickGetImageBlob(magick_wand, &my_size);
    NSData * data = [[NSData alloc] initWithBytes:my_image length:my_size];
    free(my_image);
    magick_wand = DestroyMagickWand(magick_wand);
    MagickWandTerminus();
    UIImage * image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:data];
    [data release];

    [imageViewButton setImage:image forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [image release];
}
```

The problem is that `status` is always `MagickFalse`, which means it throws an exception. I'm also not sure whether I'm using `ConvertImageCommand()` in the correct way either.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried passing 5 for the argument count? And what is the exception?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using `MagickCommandGenesis()` to achieve the desired result.

Comment: could you share an example ?
It will be very useful

Comment: I'm facing the exactly same problem, Fulvio Cusumano, could you please share your code showing how to use MagickCommandGenesis() ?

Comment: @FelipeOliveira I'm afraid I don't think I have the source code lying around anymore. I'll see if I can dig it up in the next few days, but there's no promises.

Answer (score 0):

None of these are the right answer. The code above is just plain wrong and has been copied and pasted all over the internet in some form or another

http://www.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?t=19504
http://www.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?t=25430
[iPhone ImageMagick Library - converting from batch file script to Objective-C using MagickWand API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7480812/iphone-imagemagick-library-converting-from-batch-file-script-to-objective-c-us)
http://www.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=20527

the list goes on

`MagicWand` is the framework to do image manipulations using the imagemagick API, whereas `ConvertImageCommand` calls directly into the commandline interface for the `convert` command. If you wish to do things through imagemagick's api, then use MagicWand etc, but if you wish to simply call into the same method that is used from the commandline, then call `ConvertImageCommand`.

The fact that it is returning `MagickFalse` is correct. While I don't claim to have read the whole method and know everything it's doing or why, if you look at `convert.c` http://www.imagemagick.org/api/MagickWand/convert_8c_source.html, the last few lines of the function are

```
3217   status&=WriteImages(image_info,image,argv[argc-1],exception);
 3218   if (metadata != (char **) NULL)
 3219     {
 3220       char
 3221         *text;
 3222 
 3223       text=InterpretImageProperties(image_info,image,format);
 3224       if (text == (char *) NULL)
 3225         ThrowConvertException(ResourceLimitError,"MemoryAllocationFailed",
 3226           GetExceptionMessage(errno));
 3227       (void) ConcatenateString(&(*metadata),text);
 3228       text=DestroyString(text);
 3229     }
 3230   DestroyConvert();
 3231   return(status != 0 ? MagickTrue : MagickFalse);
 3232 }
```

What it says is to return 0 (`MagickFalse`) on success when called from the commandline, which is fairly reasonable.

The above code will work fine without all the MagicWand stuff as so -

```
// Resize image.
    ImageInfo *imageInfo = AcquireImageInfo();
    ExceptionInfo *exceptionInfo = AcquireExceptionInfo();

    // Get image from bundle.
    char *input_image = strdup([[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"iphone" ofType:@"png"] UTF8String]);
    char *output_image = strdup([[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"iphone" ofType:@"png"] UTF8String]);
    char *argv[] = { "convert", input_image, "-resize", "100x100", output_image, NULL };

    // ConvertImageCommand(ImageInfo *, int, char **, char **, MagickExceptionInfo *);
    status = ConvertImageCommand(imageInfo, 5, argv, NULL, exceptionInfo);
```

Alternatively, if you want to use the API directly, then there are plenty of samples online that provide examples of how to use MagicWand.

The above code is attempting to mix and match two different methodologies. The MagicWand instantiation above is not doing anything, and if you will look at the image in the `NSData` at the end of the above code snippet, it is the same image you started with. The output of the `ConvertImageCommand` ought to be what you're expecting though.